# Regex: Match number between two strings with line breaks

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match only the value of this string that ends with **ZW-Summe** with RegEx (JavaScript, so no lookbehind - please consider: I must use regex):

```
[here is a lot more data with line breaks and so on...]
2,550%Zinsen               83,72ZW-Summe U
St         83,72Umsatzs? [more lines...]
```

Problem: There can be line breaks everyvery, even this could happen:

```
[data....] 2,550%Zinsen               83,7
2ZW-Summe U
St         83,72Umsatzs? [more lines...]
```

My goal is to match 83,72 only, without **ZW-Summe** and of course the value can change. Possible values:

- 1.000,22
- 0,22
- 222,22
- 100.000,22 and so on.

I have to identify the value with the **ZW-Summe** String because there can be more occurrences of values.

My first attempt is `((\d{0,3}((\.\d{3})){0,2}),\d{2})ZW-Sum` but this does also match ZW-Sum and I am not able to access groups - and the main problem is that I does not ignore possible line breaks.

I hope this is even possible to match something (-VALUE-ZW-Summe) and than ignore the ZW-Summe in the result?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean by *"...and I am not able to access groups..."*?

Comment: Re the line breaks: Simplest thing would be to remove them before matching.

Comment: You may use this regex: [`\b\d+(?:[,\s]*[\d.]+)*(?=ZW-Summe)`](https://regex101.com/r/2QJ1UB/1) but you will need to remove line break from matched text afterwards.

Comment: Thank you anubhava, that did the trick for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, and is quite simple: [`/([\d,.\n]+)(?=ZW-Summe)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/1HTCBE/1).

It basically just matches a series of digits, commas, periods, and newlines where after said series is `ZW-Summe` (`?=`, positive lookahead). The `g` flag makes it ignore line breaks.

After you run it, though, make sure to strip the newlines (i.e. `match = match.replace('\n', '');`).

Comment: Hmm, isn't it similar to what I posted in comments below the question?

Comment: Wasn't my question, and you should've posted it as an answer! (you still can!)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Positive lookahead did the trick for me.